# Compatibility of a metric with a left-invariant metric on a topological group

Tags: topological-groups, descriptive-set-theory

My question arised while I was reading Kechris' "Classical Descriptive Set Theory", pp. $58$.
At row $14$ of that page, the author states that

> If $d$ is a left-invariant complete metric on a metrizable topological group $G$, consider the new metric
>   $$\rho(x,y)=d(x,y)+d(x^{-1},y^{-1}).$$
>   It is easy to see that it is also compatible (but not necessarily left-invariant).

**Question:** Why is $\rho$ compatible with $d$?
Clearly $d\le \rho$, but I stuck when I try to prove the opposite implication.

If I add the extra hypothesis that $d$ is both left and right invariant, then the result follows by the fact that $d(x,y)=d(xy^{-1},1)=d(1,xy^{-1})=d(x^{-1},y^{-1})$, but this is not the case in general.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compatibility of two metrics merely means that the two metrics induce the same topologies. That is, a sequence $x_n$ converges in one if and only if it converges in the other, and this is clear here, because if $d(x_n,x)\to 0$ then by continuity of the inverse operation with respect to the metric $d$, you also have $d(x_n^{-1},x^{-1})\to 0$, so $\rho(x_n,x)\to 0$. Note that $G$ is a topological group with respect to the metric $d$, which guarantees the continuity of the group-inverse operation. Conversely, if $\rho(x_n,x)\to 0$ then clearly the non-larger nonnegative sequence also tends to zero, that is, $d(x_n,x)\to 0$.

Comment: Can I ask you a different argument? In particolar to prove compatibility I have tried to show that for any $x\in G$ the $d$-ball of radius $R$ and center $x$, if I choose $y$ in such a ball, I can find $r$ s.t. the $\rho$- ball of radius $r$ and center $y$ is contained in the $d$- ball, without success. Can explain to me how I should prove it in this way?

Comment: You should first do it for the special case that $x=e$, where $e$ is the unit element of the group, and then given arbitrary $x\in G$ use the fact that multiplication by $x^{-1}$ is a homemorphism of the group onto itself.

Comment: Also because, ad I understand it, your proof is "too clever" in the sense that you don't need left invariance

Comment: Ok I try to do that. If it is difficult for me, I Will ask your help. Thank you very much.

Comment: There is no need in left invariance. The whole point of the example is to demonstrate that there exist two compatible metrics; one left-invariant and the other not necessarily so. Their compatibility has nothing to do with left invariance.

Comment: When $x=e$, then I want to prove that for every $d$-ball $B(e,R)$ there exists a $\rho$-ball $B(e,r)$ s.t. $B(e,r)^{-1}\subseteq B(e,R)$. How should I choose $r$?